# Why Future isDone() block the program like Future get()?

Tags: java, multithreading, javafx-8, java.util.concurrent

I'm writing a program for generating fractal and fractal animation, the problem is on the animation...

I have a main thread that generate a `List<Callable<Long>> tasks` where each element has the information and resources for generate one frame; then i use an `ExecutorService` to submit the work.

The problem is in the impossibility to cancel these secondary thread if the user want to stop the calculus. Here is the code:

```
public class Animation extends Task<Long> {
protected Long call() throws Exception {
    long startTime = System.currentTimeMillis();

    WritableImage[] frames = new WritableImage[frameNumber];
    List<Callable<Long>> tasks = new ArrayList<>();

    updateProgress(count.incrementAndGet(), maxCount);
    if (isCancelled()) {
        return System.currentTimeMillis() - startTime;;
    }

    for (int k = 0; k < frameNumber; k++) {
        frames[k] = new WritableImage(
                (int) start.getCartesianPlane().getWidth(),
                (int) start.getCartesianPlane().getHeight());

        CartesianFractal tmp = FractalFactory.bulidFractal(
                selectedFractal, nextDataBox(k), colorPalette);

        tmp.setOnFinish(t -> {
            updateProgress(count.incrementAndGet(), maxCount);
            return null;
        });

        tasks.add((Callable<Long>) tmp);
        if (isCancelled()) {
            return System.currentTimeMillis() - startTime;;
        }
    }

    executor = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(4);
    updateProgress(count.incrementAndGet(), maxCount);
    if (isCancelled()) {
        return System.currentTimeMillis() - startTime;
    }
    try {
        result = executor.invokeAll(tasks);
    }
    catch (InterruptedException ex) {
        System.err.println(ex.toString());
    }

    // Check if all tasks are finished
    boolean finished = false;
    while (!finished) {
        finished = true;
        // Check if it is all done
        for (Future<Long> r : result) {
            finished = finished && r.isDone(); // THE PROGRAM BLOCKS HERE
            // Check if the task was cancelled
            if (isCancelled()) {
                // Cancell all task
                tasks.stream().forEach((t) -> {
                    ((CartesianFractal)t).myCancel();
                });
                // Turnoff the executor
                executor.shutdown();
                return System.currentTimeMillis() - startTime;
            }
        }
    }

    // Turnoff the executor
    executor.shutdown();
    updateProgress(count.incrementAndGet(), maxCount);

    makeAnimation();
    updateProgress(count.incrementAndGet(), maxCount);

    return System.currentTimeMillis() - startTime;
}
}
```

I really don't understood why `Future.isDone()` block the program like `Future.get()` !

This is my first question, so i hope it's all ok.

Comment: Does it *really* block there (as in the thread is in `BLOCKED` state), or does it just seem to be stopped on that line because it's busy-waiting?

Comment: By the way, a `CompletionService` might be an easier way to be notified when a thread completes.

Comment: Another BTW: rather than have `return System.currentTimeMillis() - startTime;` scattered through your code, you can split most of the logic into `void callInternal()`, which is called from `call() { long startTime = ...; callInternal(); return System.currentTimeMillis() - startTime; }`. Also, consider putting the `executor.shutDown()` into a single `finally` block.

Comment: (...or write a general `TimedCallable` class, which wraps a call to a delegate `Callable` (or `Runnable`, I suppose), so you can reuse the timing logic elsewhere).

Answer (score 2):

I think that it might be easier if you implemented this using a `CompletionService`, which returns you `Future`s in the order that they complete.

For example:

```
Executor executor = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(4);

try {
    CompletionService completionService = new ExecutorCompletionService(executor);

    List<Future<Long>> futures = new ArrayList<>();
    for (Callable<Long> task : task) {
    futures.add(completionService.submit(task));
  }

  int pending = futures.size();
  while (pending > 0) {
      // Wait for up to 100ms to see if anything has completed.
      // The completed future is returned if one is found; otherwise null.
      // (Tune 100ms as desired)
      Future<Long> completed = completionService.poll(100, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS);
      if (completed != null) {
          updateProgress(count.incrementAndGet(), maxCount);
          --pending;
    }
    if (isCancelled()) {
        // Cancel all task etc.
        break;
    }
  }
} finally {
    executor.shutdown();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Thanks for the time and help you have give me!

The program seem to be only busy, so i have found this solution: for cancel all jobs i use this code:

```
if (task != null) {
    task.myCancel();
    task.cancel();
}
```

While the `Animation` class become:

```
public class Animation extends Task<Long> {
[...]
@Override
protected Long call() throws Exception {
    long startTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
    ExecutorService executor = null;

    try {
        frames = new WritableImage[frameNumber];
        updateProgress(count.incrementAndGet(), maxCount);
        if (isCancelled()) {
            return System.currentTimeMillis() - startTime;
        }

        executor = Executors.newWorkStealingPool();
        //executor = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(4);
        updateProgress(count.incrementAndGet(), maxCount);
        if (isCancelled()) {
            return System.currentTimeMillis() - startTime;
        }

        tasks = initTasks();
        updateProgress(count.incrementAndGet(), maxCount);
        if (isCancelled()) {
            return System.currentTimeMillis() - startTime;
        }

        result = executor.invokeAll(tasks);
        updateProgress(count.incrementAndGet(), maxCount);

        makeAnimation();
        updateProgress(count.incrementAndGet(), maxCount);
    }
    catch (InterruptedException ex) {
        System.err.println(ex.toString());
    }
    finally {
        if (executor != null) {
            executor.shutdown();
        }
    }

    return System.currentTimeMillis() - startTime;
}
[...]
public void myCancel() {
    tasks.stream().forEach((t) -> {
        ((CartesianFractal)t).myCancel();
    });
}
[...]
}
```